# How to restrict BigQuery API User for selective Users?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, quota, google-bigquery-storage-api

I want to set a quota of daily BigQuery Query usage for selective users. As per the document, we can set Query usage Quota for all users, not selective users.

**Is there any way to set up Quota over BigQuery API in the same project as below?**

- User-1/Principal-1 - 500GB
- User-2/Principal-2 - 5GB
- User-3/Principal-3 - 1TB
- User-4/Principal-4 - `Unlimited`

Answer (score 1):

Creating a [custom quota](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/custom-quotas) on query data allows you to control costs at the project-level or at the user-level.

- Project-level custom quotas limit the aggregate usage of all users in that project.
- User-level custom quotas are separately applied to all users and service accounts within a project.

> **It is not possible to assign a custom quota to a specific user or service account.**

However, there is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/119608422) filed for the same. You can vote for this feature by clicking the `+1` and `STAR` mark to receive updates on it.